# How can i fix the slider error, scroll to is not a function?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a website www.save-nature-group.de There I use a slider in the head of the front page. But the slider is not working because of a javascript error (scroll to is not a function). Maybe somebody can help me with this. I can't read or write Java Script. That's why I am not able to fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it you can:
1. In the Slider Settings -> Troubleshooting set option: **Put JS Includes To Body** option to true.
2. Find the double jquery.js include and remove it.

Turn on "Put JS includes to body"

Comment: i have no slider settings in the wordpress backend :-( The slider is included in the wordpress thesis skin. mh...any ideas?